# Ubuntu not installing after hard drive got wiped

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I have tried everything. Making a Live USB, opening up the PC so I can manually load the ISO files into it and boot from there, Unplugging the USB at various times, but Ubuntu is not installing.

The one time it seemed to be working (it got onto the "installation in progress" page,) the progress bar was not moving. The Terminal said "unable to remove directory" or "unable to connect to server" or things like that.

PC specs:

- Quad core processor @ 2.4 GHZ
- 12 GB RAM
- 1 TB 7200 RPM Hard Drive
- UEFI boot
- 3x USB ports
- 1080p display
- Graphics: Intel Haswell Mobile

**UPDATE:**

I have gotten it to the choose timezone part, and the installation gets locked up on the "force uefi installation?" popup.

Comment: There will be an option on the initial menu to 'Check this disk and install Ubuntu'. Can you run this and see what it says? Your install media may be corrupt.

Comment: It says the disk has no defects

Comment: What brand/model system? And what video card/chip? Was drive partitioned before. If drive was gpt, then you may need to boot installer in UEFI mode. Or if MBR in BIOS mode. Better to repartion in advance and install in UEFI mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and: Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
and Also shows Windows 10 screens http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: My hard drive got wiped, and that is why I am installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY GOT IT TO WORK!!!
Apparently I was using the wrong USB port (go figure!)

Answer (score 1):

Go into your BIOS/firmware setup when the computer first boots and change the boot type to "legacy" if you aren't worried about using UEFI/EFI boot.

This should get you up and running again.

Personally, I prefer UEFI/EFI but it's not absolutely necessary. Just use legacy mode (sometimes called compatibility mode).

Comment: it is not working for BIOS either

Comment: Try and create a CD with the ISO file you downloaded.

Comment: my laptop doesn't have a cd drive. Only USB and that is what I am trying to use now.